# Which movies from The Infinity Saga show an Infinity stone or its container?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe

Regarding the movies of [the Infinity Saga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_films#%22The_Infinity_Saga%22) (23 movie so far), which ones actually show an Infinity stone or its container as part of the plot? Not counting mid-credits or post-credits references.

**Captain America: The First Avenger** and **The Avengers** have the Tesseract (Space stone).
**Thor: The Dark World** for the Aether (Reality stone).
**Guardians of the Galaxy** for the Power stone.
**Avengers: Age of Ultron** for Loki's scepter (Mind stone).
**Doctor Strange** for the Eye of Agamotto (Time stone).

And obviously, **Avengers: Infinity War** and **Avengers: Endgame**.

Any other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Thor: Ragnarok*** shows the Tesseract in Odin’s vault and an (apparently fake) Infinity Gauntlet loaded with gems.

[image]

[image]

Neither play a substantial part in the plot, but appear in the main film nevertheless.

Also, Doctor Strange appears in the film and as such you can see him carrying the Eye of Agamaotto, although it’s not used (and I’m not even sure it’s referenced).

[image]

***Captain America: Civil War*** features Vision, who bears the Mind Stone in his forehead.

[image]

The Tesseract appears in ***Captain Marvel***, and plays a big part in the plot, being revealed as

> The source of the main character’s powers.

Comment: That's a total of 11 movies out of 23: roughly 50% of them feature an Infinity stone. Thank you.